# line break or second row for single record in view?

Tags: views, 6

I'm using views2 in Drupal 6. I have a view for a custom table. One of the column is called 'notes', which is a textarea. Most of the time it's blank, but sometimes not.

I would like to have it so that if there is a value in the notes column, instead of displaying it in the column, it would add a line break or another row underneath the normal values, like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4 |
| this is a note.               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is this possible to do with built-in views functionality, or is there a module that can accomplish this?

Comment: But I am wondering how views will know about your custom entity notes.

Comment: @Shoaib The same way it knows about the other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your 'notes' field to your view, but exclude it from display (in views field settings), then output it in any way you want (as new table row for example) using views' Theming Information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for Drupal 7 and Views 3.x called [Views Secondary Row](http://drupal.org/project/views_secondary_row). Sadly, it's not available for Drupal 6 or Views 2.x.

---

A first-glance at the code of Views Secondary Row makes me think that a backport to Drupal 6 and Views 6.x-3.x might not be too difficult if you have some module-development experience (although I've never written modules to work with Views before, so I'm not sure how accurate that observation is). If you don't want to try your hand at it personally, you could put a feature request in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/views_secondary_row).

Comment: This is a great solution for D7. Can do lots of things including line breaks, etc.